# document.onload function is not executed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an index.html file which includes a javascript file. Javascript file has a document.onload function which never gets executed. Can someone tell me why is this not being executed when DOM is loaded.

```js
console.log("javascript file started loading");
document.onload = function () {
  console.log("document loaded");
  alert("DOM is ready");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <h1>cool page onload</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Xufox my question is when will document.onload function be executed . If it will not be executed then what is the use of this function?

Comment: The accepted answer of the dup answers that question too: "_... the browser will not do anything special with it._". It's just a custom function like `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

onload in window,not document

```
window.onload = function () {
  console.log("document loaded");
  alert("DOM is ready");
}
```

if you want to use document,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("document loaded");
    alert("DOM is ready");
});
```

Comment: window.onload function will be executed when the DOM, css files, images and everything is loaded. I want the document.onload function to be executed when the dom is loaded

Comment: already suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: @user3807454,so you can use DOMContentLoaded,see my answer

Answer (score -2):

The function document works if you apply jQuery to your website. Also make sure that your script tag is before the closing body tag so that the DOM can load.

Comment: This question is not about jQuery.